# Move specific column from csv file in front (select column by name)

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, csv

Consider this data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > example_file.txt <<EOL
group, value, price
1, 3.21, 3.21
1, 3.42, 4.11
1, 3.5, 1.22
2, 4.1, 9.2
2, 4.2, 2.11
EOL
```

I want to move the 'value' column in front:

```
value, price, group
3.21, 3.21, 1
3.42, 4.11, 1
3.5, 1.22, 1
4.1, 9.2, 2
4.2, 2.11, 2
```

the problem is: the order of the column (or even the number of column or the name of many of those columns --except 'value' which is always there) varies from file to file. So I have to select the value column by name (not order).

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need to output the additional columns - or just `value,price,group` in that order regardless of what other columns may exist?

Comment: all the original columns but with value now moved to being the first one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind the `value` column being duplicated, you could do something like this, with `csvtool`:

```
$ csvtool paste <(csvtool namedcol value example_file.txt) example_file.txt 
value,group,value,price
3.21,1,3.21,3.21
3.42,1,3.42,4.11
3.5,1,3.5,1.22
4.1,2,4.1,9.2
4.2,2,4.2,2.11
```

However as far as I know `csvtool` won't *move* (or *remove*) a `namedcol`.

If you can't find a specialized CSV tool that will, you can roll your own using a general purpose language such as Awk or Perl. The idea would be to search the fields of the first row for the index of the matching column, then [slice and dice](https://perlmaven.com/splice-to-slice-and-dice-arrays-in-perl) the fields in the chosen order.

For example using the perl [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module, and this trick [How to get the index of specific element (value) of an array?](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-get-index-of-element-in-array)

```
$ perl -MText::CSV -lpe '
  BEGIN{ $p = Text::CSV->new({ allow_whitespace => 1 }) };
  @f = $p->fields() if $p->parse($_);
  ($i) = grep { $f[$_] eq "value" } (0..$#f) if $. == 1; 
  $_ = join ", ", splice(@f, $i, 1),  @f
' example_file.txt
value, group, price
3.21, 1, 3.21
3.42, 1, 4.11
3.5, 1, 1.22
4.1, 2, 9.2
4.2, 2, 2.11
```

Comment: Fantastic! I will throw a bounty your way to attract attention to this great answer asap

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now find aborruso's answer the simplest to use for this problem.

Answer (score 11):

With the great [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) ([docs](https://miller.readthedocs.io/)) is very easy
mlr --csv reorder -f " value, price,group" input.csv

you have

```
 value, price,group
 3.21, 3.21,1
 3.42, 4.11,1
 3.5, 1.22,1
 4.1, 9.2,2
 4.2, 2.11,2
```

Please note: I have edited my command, taking into account the spaces in fields name of the question CSV.

Comment: I would like to upvote your answer because of its simplicity, but it does not work...The output I get is identical to the input :-(

Comment: hi @zx485 I'm using this csv https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aborruso/4d316e39c572e589af4046ade8e26c13/raw/d241f391f4170b8c17425288ec14c25365798803/input.csv Please look also at this video http://youtu.be/XcTXaxKy-t4?hd=1

Comment: I looked at both, but `mlr` aka miller still doesn't do what it's supposed to do. I got it from the repositories of Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @zx485 please tell me the version you have (`mlr --version`)

Comment: It's `Miller 5.3.0`.

Comment: @zx485 I have `Miller 5.4.0-dev`. You could try with a more recente binary  https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/download/5.4.0/mlr.linux.x86_64 Please try to use this alternative command `mlr --csv cut -o -f value,price,group input.csv`

Comment: I used the version `5.4.0` but it's still not working :-( And the alternative command only outputs only the first value(s).

Comment: @zx485 you should open an issue https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues Could you share your input csv and the output of your command?

Comment: My input CSV is from the question. The output is identical to the input. It's as simple as that, nothing is done to the input file.

Comment: @zx485 if you use the CSV of the question, there is some space in fields name, then the command is `mlr --csv reorder -f " value, price,group" input.csv`

Comment: Thank you. Removing the spaces from the CSV did the trick. But this is a really nasty behaviour.

Comment: You are welcome @zx485! But why nasty? As you can read in [CSV RFC](https://hyp.is/u1HHsB2QEem3X9t-ZqI-qw/tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) " Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored": than it's necessary to take in account spaces in field name.

Comment: Well then. I didn't knew that. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'm only just discovering Miller - IMHO this is a much better answer than the currently accepted one (mine). You could also just do `reorder -e -f group` to move `group` to the **e**nd.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Set a default value of the LABEL of the target column that must become first column
if [[ -z ${LABEL+x} ]]; then LABEL='value'; fi

# Process a single FILE
move_the_label_column_first() {
    # Read the LABELS on the first line of the input file as an array
    IFS=', ' read -a LABELS < <(cat "$FILE" 2>/dev/null | head -n1)

    # Find the number of the target column
    for ((COL = 0; COL < ${#LABELS[@]}; ++COL))
    do
        if [[ ${LABELS[$COL]} == "$LABEL" ]]
        then
            break
        fi
    done

    # Read each LINE from the input file as an array and output it in the new order
    while IFS=', ' read -a LINE
    do
        printf '%s, ' "${LINE[$COL]}" "${LINE[@]:0:$COL}" "${LINE[@]:$((COL + 1))}" | \
        sed 's/, $/\n/'
    done < <(cat "$FILE" 2>/dev/null)
}

# Process all input files, exclude the current script filename
for FILE in "$@"
do
    if [[ -f $FILE ]] && [[ $FILE != $(basename "$0") ]]
    then
        #echo "Input file: $FILE"
        move_the_label_column_first
    fi
done
```

Let's call the script `reorder.sh`. To illustrate the script's capabilities let's assume there are the following files we want to process and they are located in the same directory where our script is.

```bsh
$ cat in-file-1 
group, value, price
1, 3.21, 3.21
1, 3.42, 4.11
1, 3.5, 1.22

$ cat in-file-2
price, group, value, other
3.21, 1, 3.21, 7
4.11, 1, 3.42, 13
1.22, 1, 3.5, -1
```

Process one input file:

```bsh
$ ./reorder.sh in-file-1 
value, group, price
3.21, 1, 3.21
3.42, 1, 4.11
3.5, 1, 1.22
```

Process two input files and change the label of the column that must become first column to `price`:

```bsh
$ LABEL='price' ./reorder.sh in-file-1 in-file-2 
price, group, value
3.21, 1, 3.21
4.11, 1, 3.42
1.22, 1, 3.5
price, group, value, other
3.21, 1, 3.21, 7
4.11, 1, 3.42, 13
1.22, 1, 3.5, -1
```

Process all files in the directory:

```bsh
$ ./reorder.sh *
value, group, price
3.21, 1, 3.21
3.42, 1, 4.11
3.5, 1, 1.22
value, price, group, other
3.21, 3.21, 1, 7
3.42, 4.11, 1, 13
3.5, 1.22, 1, -1
```

Process recursively:

```bsh
$ shopt -s globstar
$ ./reorder.sh **/*
value, group, price
3.21, 1, 3.21
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1). I find aborruso's to be the simplest to use in the sense that it all happens 'under the fold'.

Comment: @user2413, thanks. Yes, aborruso's answer looks nice and simple, but I didn't succeed with it. However, my suggestion is most portable of the 4 solutions provided up to this moment :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `csvtool` it can be done with a small shell-script wrapper:

```
# Make sure that the value column isn't in front already
if head -n 1 example_file.txt | grep -q '^value,'; then
    # Value already in front
    exit
fi

# Calculate the position of value in the header (1-indexed, as thats what csvtool use)
pos=$(($(head -n 1 example_file.txt | sed -e 's/, value\(,.*\|$\)//' | tr -d -c ',' | wc -c)+2))

# Move the value column as the pos-position to the front
csvtool col $pos,1-$((pos-1)),$((pos+1))- example_file.txt > example_file_fixed.txt
```

The wrapper here figures out at what position the value column is in, in the header (by counting commas before value). It then uses the `csvtool` command to rearrange the columns into `value, <columns before>, <columns after>`.